# shaded region question

Tags: geometry

*The width of the rectangle a b c d below is equal to one third of
its length, and its perimeter equals 64 cm. What is the area of the
shaded parts in square centimeters?*

**Please help me solve this question. Thank you :)**

[image]

[The image is not the exact one, I mean the measurements are not correctly marked but the shading is right. I want to find the area of the blue regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhqv.png)

Comment: $12$ is not one third of $18$

Comment: What is known about the white triangle? It's base appears smaller than the length of the rectangle. Is the apex a right angle?

Comment: How is the top vertix of the triangle placed? without that information one cannot answer

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the correct diagram! I got it though! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram is not consistent with your question.

Let's suppose your diagram should look more like this:

[image]

Then the perimeter of the rectangle would be $8s$ and if this were $64\,cm$ then $s=8\,cm$ and $3s=24\,cm$ making the area of the rectangle $192\,cm^2$ and the blue area half that namely $96\,cm^2$

Comment: Yes that's the correct diagram!! Thank you so very much!! :)